# Single FormGroup for many components that should be visable one at a time

Tags: angular

I have a complicated form that need to be divided to few components with side navigation (to navigate to each component). we show one component each time according to the user position in the navigation bar.

Only when the user finish to fill the data in all the components he can click "Submit".

i know that i can do it with routing and save the state of each component in a service and then send all the data together using http but i am wondering if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Look into FormArrays. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

You will be able to create one big form that has multiple FormGroups, FormControls etc... in it. You'll be able to show only one FormGroup at a time, and submit the whole FormArray at the end.